# Unnecessary reads in memory mapped files when writing only

Tags: windows, memory-mapped-files

I'm having a simple application that is just writing into a memory mapped file, without ever reading from it. So what I'm doing is to have a simple loop that writes 50 blocks of an array of the size 4096*100 into the memory mapped file or better into the memory represented by the memory mapped file. Since I'm only writing to it I thought there will never by a read IRP request, but obviously 20 read IRP issues (which in total corresponds to the memory I'm writing and is a multiple of the sector size), whereas there is only one write. The interesting thing is that the write is even performend since there is enough memory and the file was marked with DeleteOnClose, so there would be no need to write it when the result is discarded. But this might be a problem of the implementation of the memory mapped files in .NET (see here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/59606)

Im bothered by the fact that unncessary reads are performed. The problem is that there is mostly now real knowledge about memory mapped files since most of my answer stay unanswered. So maybe someone can guide me to some sources where I can find more information abiut memory mapped files.

**[Update 1]**
I'm currently doing my own file-mapping, without using memory mapped files, here I'm simply allocating memory, if the file was allocated fresh. So I know that the memory has never been written before. I would expect something similar from the MMF-Files.

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles;

namespace MemoryMappedFileTest
{
    class Program
    {
        // Size of a single block in bytes
        const int SizeOfBlock = 4096 * 100;

        // Number of blocks.
        const int NoOfBlocks = 50;

        // Name of the test file.
        const string FileName = "E:\\MMF\\mm.dat";

        static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create the temporary which is deleted on close.
            using var stream = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite, 4096, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose);

            // Create the file mapping and the view
            using var mm = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(stream, null, NoOfBlocks * (long)SizeOfBlock, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite, HandleInheritability.None, false);
            using var va = mm.CreateViewAccessor();

            // Get the absolute start address
            var StartAddress = va.SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle.DangerousGetHandle();

            // Create some empty block data we can write.
            var BlockData = new byte[SizeOfBlock];

            // Run through the blocks and write 0s in it.
            for (int blockNo = 0; blockNo < NoOfBlocks; blockNo++)
            {
                // Get the address of the block
                byte* blockAddress = (byte*)StartAddress + checked(blockNo * (long)SizeOfBlock);

                // Work with spans
                Span<byte> blockSpan = new(blockAddress, SizeOfBlock);
                for (int i = 0; i < SizeOfBlock; i++)
                    blockSpan[i] = 0;
                //BlockData.CopyTo(blockSpan);

                // Print the blockNo.
                Console.WriteLine(blockNo);
            };

            Console.WriteLine("Done");

            stream.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's how memory-mapped files work. They read on first access, even if the first access is a write, because that written first byte has to be merged with the rest of the existing data. It looks like a memory-mapped file is the wrong tool for this job. Just Write the blocks.

Comment: @RaymondChen. Thanks for the feedback. I agree with the merge, if they wouldn't be a multiple of the page size, but if the block exactly matches a multiple of the page size it could simply write because a merge is not required. But then it would required some sort of a block write method and I' m not aware if this exists. Additionally, the file is created newly, so a merge wouldn't be helpful at all, right?

The example is simplified to show my findings. In the end I need the MM-File capabilities.

Do you know any good source or discussion partner that has deep insight into MM-Files?

Comment: I have added an update comment [Update 1] of how I solve the problem currently not using MM-Files.

Comment: The system cannot see the future. It sees that you wrote one byte. (`blockSpan[i] = 0`.) It doesn't know that you're going to write 4095 more bytes before anybody else reads the block. Maybe there's another program running on the system that opens the file `E:\MMF\mm.dat` as a memory-mapped file a second time, and starts reading/writing it. Now that initial read and merged block is important.

Comment: @RaymondChen: "The system cannot see the future. It sees that you wrote one byte. (blockSpan[i] = 0". I agree, but what if there would be an API that advises a blockcopy? CopyMemory obviously doesn't have this capabilities ( I tried and it has the same behavior as the CopyTo) and I do not know if there's such a method.

Comment: It would be rather expensive because it would have to block all access to the memory mapped region during the copy, in case another thread or process was reading from the region at the same time you are copying into it. This could lead to priority inversion problems. Maybe don't use a memory mapped file to initialize the file. Initialize the file with normal writes, and then memory map it when finished.

Comment: OK. That makes sense. Thanks.